# Converting (web site) text file into data frame in R

Tags: r, text, dataframe

I have a text file from a sports betting website and want to convert the lines into a data frame.

The textfile looks like that:

```
18 May 2013 1   X   2   B's
15:30   Augsburg - Greuther 3:1 
1.43
4.55
7.27
16
18:30   Dortmund - Hoffenheim   1:2 
1.39
5.23
6.79
16
11 May 2013 1   X   2   B's
15:30   Bayer - Hannover    3:1 
1.29
5.77
9.46
16
```

The data frame should look like this afterwards:

```
Date        Time    Team1       Team2       G1  G2  1   0   2
18 May 2013 15:30   Augsburg    Greuther    3   1   1.43    4.55    7.27
18 May 2013 18:30   Dortmund    Hoffenheim  1   2   1.39    5.23    6.79
11 May 2013 15:30   Bayer       Hannover    3   1   1.29    5.77    9.46
```

I was thinking about some for loop where I check whether or not the line I am in contains a date or not. I would set a variable as current_date and if there is no new date it wont be updated to a new date.
For example the first to matches are both on the same day so the date-variable will stay May18 for the 2nd line.

I would want to produces vectors containing current date, time, team1, team2, result(Goals1, goals2), and then the odds for winning, draw, losing.

And then just rbind them under one another.

The most problems I think I would have with reading line after line of the data file and checking the type.
Can one specify that after the time the next character is team1 and after "-" comes team2 and before and after ":" is G1 and G2 and that the next three lines will just be included raw into that vector?

I am also not sure if a for loop would be the smartest idea if the txt file gets around 20,000 lines.
Also the 4th line after the time shoudl be excluded.

I am sorry if I ask questions like that, I know I could try out stuff for some more hours and post my code here but I would probably end up with insufficient half-baked code :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try

```
lines <- readLines("clipboard") # copy the sample text file to clipboard first
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
idx_dates <- strptime(lines, "%d %B %Y")
idx_dates <- which(!is.na(idx_dates))
idx_times <- grep("[0-9]+:[0-9]+", lines)

parse_item <- function(i) {
    date <- lines[[max(idx_dates[idx_dates < i])]]
    date <- substr(date, 1, nchar(date)-16)    
    date <- paste(date, substr(lines[[i]], 1, 5))
    date <- strptime(date, "%d %B %Y %H:%M")
    teamsgoals <- substring(lines[[i]], 9)
    teamsgoals <- gsub(" +", " ", teamsgoals)
    teamsgoals <- strsplit(teamsgoals, " ")[[1]]
    team1 <- teamsgoals[1]
    team2 <- teamsgoals[3]
    goals <- strsplit(teamsgoals[4], ":")[[1]]
    g1 <- as.numeric(goals[1])
    g2 <- as.numeric(goals[2])
    q1 <- as.numeric(lines[[i+1]])
    q0 <- as.numeric(lines[[i+2]])
    q2 <- as.numeric(lines[[i+3]])
    data.frame(date=date, team1=team1, team2=team2, g1=g1, g2=g2, q1=q1, q0=q0, q2=q2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

parsed <- lapply(idx_times, FUN=parse_item)
Reduce(rbind, parsed)
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
```

which returns

```
                 date    team1      team2 g1 g2   q1   q0   q2
1 2013-05-18 15:30:00 Augsburg   Greuther  3  1 1.43 4.55 7.27
2 2013-05-18 18:30:00 Dortmund Hoffenheim  1  2 1.39 5.23 6.79
3 2013-05-11 15:30:00    Bayer   Hannover  3  1 1.29 5.77 9.46
```

Comment: Hi Karsten, the result looks exactly like what I was hoping to get. Now I try to understand the function you wrote more thoroughly. The sys.set/getlocal I haven't seen before (but those are self explaining). The reduce() I have to check and how the idx_times work exactly with the grep() command. Since the go in the lapply() function I should be sure how they work. Vielen Dank auf jeden Fall für deine Mühe.

Comment: Just pass the filename to `readLines` instead of "clipboard". The `idx_times <- grep(...)` command uses a regular expression to identify the lines which match one or more digits [0-9]+, followed by a colon, followed by one or more digits. BTW, at which site did you scrape the quotes?

Comment: The strptime() is super usefull to get the lines that contain the date information. But the grep() command is still a complete mistery to me and only gave me: integer(0) as a result. Maybe I need another package for that first. I did not technically "scrape" the data properly from the web but copy pasted it. I think I had to do every Spieltag by hand (coz I dont know how to scrape through websites and extract the html code) it wasnt that much work. I have to check the website that had the quotes (even from last years).

Comment: I send you an email with the quote-link

Comment: Still struggling with the grep(). So I think the question marks should be pluses in the code, right? "[0-9]+" etc not "[0-9]?". If I change that I get the "lines" containing those combintations. But what is the ] .*" meaning in the end?

Comment: ...a minor bug: the -16 should be -10 but I think that was my mistake, because it is not very clear that the date comes as this:date
[1] "18 May 2013\t1\tX\t2\tB's" and that it is 10 characters from the end before reaching the year.

Comment: The regex can be simplified as you suggested, I fixed that. The `idx_times` is used only as argument to the `parse_item` function. I did not understand the -16/-10 thing, though.

Comment: So there are a bit more "bugs" but not because of your code, but because my txt file is slightly different than the example text i provided. It is now all about cutting the lines properly into teams and results. So I have to fiddle around with gsub, substr and substring. But its clear to me how it will work and how to access the different output results from stringsplit etc. So I think I will make it :)

Comment: You define the endpoint of the date <- substr(date, 1, nchar(date)-16)  with nchar and -16. But the date is  "18 May 2013\t1\tX\t2\tB's" and if you use -16 you get nchar(date) =21-16=5 so only "18 Ma" as a result. With -10 you get 11 as the end point and then: "18 May 2013" which I guess is what we want as the date.

Answer (score 0):

This example has tips on how to create data frames with web data.

http://giventhedata.blogspot.com/2012/08/r-and-web-for-beginners-part-iii.html

Comment: Sorry, those tutorials might be alright, but the weren't particularly helpful for my problem. But thanks for trying.