# Converting text file into data frame in R

Tags: r, import, read.table

My raw data is in a text file with no particular delimiters between the values, like so:

```
101  10.08  S   A  05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE  4110   6548   6404   55930
```

Applying read.table in R creates a data frame with only one variable per row, whereas I would like a data frame with 10 variables per row (one for each of the 10 values). How can I achieve this if there is no delimiter in the text file?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302986/converting-web-site-text-file-into-data-frame-in-r

Comment: You need to post code if you wnat us to understand why you "only get one variable per row"?

Comment: Do you want the 12-space-delimited values in your example row to be randomly allocated to 10 values? If that's not the case, you need to be specific about whether there is any rules/patterns in terms of delimiting each row.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that each field consist of non-spaces except for field 6 which may have embedded spaces.

**Create test file**

```
Lines <- "101 10.08 S A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 55930
101 10.08 S A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 55930
"
cat(Lines, file = "myfile.txt")
```

**Run**. Read in the file using `readLines` producing `L`.  Then using `gsubfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) insert the character defined by `sep` between the fields producing `g`. 
Finally read the text in `g` using `read.table` to create a data frame:

```
library(gsubfn)
L <- readLines("myfile.txt")

sep <- ";"  # choose any character not in the file

pat <- "(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S.*\\S) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+)"
pat <- gsub(" ", "\\s+", pat) # can omit if there is only 1 space between fields
g <- gsubfn(pat, ... ~ paste(..., sep = sep), L)

read.table(text = g, sep = sep)
```

**Output**. The result of the last line is:

```
   V1    V2 V3 V4      V5                 V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
1 101 10.08  S  A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 1010
2 101 10.08  S  A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 1010
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about there only being ten columns?

```
> read.table(text="101 10.08 S A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 55930")
   V1    V2 V3 V4      V5     V6   V7     V8   V9  V10  V11   V12
1 101 10.08  S  A 05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE 4110 6548 6404 55930
```

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is that this is a fixed width format file. We would get a better understanding of this possibility if you posted several lines:

```
require(foreign)
txt2 <- "101  10.08  S   A  05OCT93 GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE  4110   6548   6404   55930"
read.fwf(file=textConnection(txt2), c(4,6,3,4,9,20,6,8,8,8))
   V1    V2  V3   V4        V5                   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10
1 101 10.08   S    A   05OCT93  GOLDEN GATE BRIDGE  4110 6548 6404 55930
```