# Copy data in a column and paste in a line of syntax

Tags: r, text

I attend a video lecture from coursera. I got a table of data of salaries like this.

```
data02 = read.table("~/R/introstats/NYRedBullsSalaries.txt", header = F)
```

The table is like this:

```
           V1
1    33750.00
2    44000.00
3   138188.00
4    45566.67
5    44000.00
```

I want to copy all the data in V1 into one line, retaining the format as numeric. I typed the syntax like this:

```
salaries = paste(as.character(data02), sep = " ", collapse =",")
salaries
```

and it works.

```
# [1] "c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)"
```

But when I want to make a box plot, it fails:

```
boxplot(salaries)
## Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)]
```

**non-numeric argument to binary operator**

I could only make it by manually copying the bunch of numbers:

```
salaries_revised = c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)
boxplot(salaries_revised)
```

Question:

It is OK if I handle 5 pieces of data. But it's impossible to highlight and copy 5,000 pieces of data. Can you tell me how to copy a large pile of data without manual input?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297564/converting-text-file-into-data-frame-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `boxplot` by just using

```
 boxplot(data02) #it will give a boxplot for each column
```

From the post, I am assuming that you want to mimic the output that is generated using

```
salaries_revised = c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)
str(salaries_revised)
#num [1:5] 33750 44000 138188 45567 44000
```

You don't have to manually copy the elements to get the correct format for `boxplot` input dataset.  Just do:

```
salaries_revised <- data02[,"V1"]
```

Or

```
salaries_revised <- data02$V1

str(salaries_revised)
# num [1:5] 33750 44000 138188 45567 44000
```

Regarding the `paste` code you used, it is creating a single character `string`

```
salaries <- paste(as.character(data02), sep = " ", collapse =",")
str(salaries)
# chr "c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)"
```

One way to get the result you wanted is to use `eval(parse(..`

```
boxplot(eval(parse(text=salaries)))
```

You don't even need the `paste` to get the above string

```
 as.character(data02)
 #[1] "c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)"

 boxplot(eval(parse(text=as.character(data02))))
```

Also, you were using the entire `data.frame` for the `paste`.  Suppose, your dataset have multiple columns.

```
data03 <- data02
data03$V2 <- 1:5
as.character(data03)
#[1] "c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)"
#[2] "1:5"
```

The `eval(parse(..)` directly on the above will return only the last element

```
 eval(parse(text=as.character(data03)))
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Using `paste`

```
salaries <- paste(as.character(data03), sep = " ", collapse =",")
salaries 
#[1] "c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000),1:5"
```

It will end up with error.

```
boxplot(eval(parse(text=salaries)))
#Error in parse(text = salaries) : <text>:1:41: unexpected ','
```

If you need only the `V1` column

```
 salaries <- paste(as.character(data03[,"V1", drop=FALSE]), 
                                       sep = " ", collapse =",")
```

When you try to subset a single column from a dataset by default, it gets converted to `vector`.  So, you can avoid that by specifying `drop=FALSE`.

Or

```
 salaries <- paste0("c(",paste(as.character(data03[,"V1"]),
                                        sep=" ", collapse=","), ")") 

 salaries
 #[1] "c(33750,44000,138188,45566.67,44000)"
```

#### data

```
 data02 <- structure(list(V1 = c(33750, 44000, 138188, 45566.67, 44000)), 
 .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Nice and thorough explanation! One little thing you might add is a short note of the drop = False/True argument in [. (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much, David!

The most wonderful thing is the code [boxplot(eval(parse(text=as.character(data02))))]

Then I don't need to copy the chunk of numbers in plotting graphs or other calculations.