# How to plot Rule based Decision tree in R

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am just starting with R and I am having a difficulty in plotting a rule based decision tree in R.

The problem is, I already have an output from hadoop MapReduce and it is in the form of a simple text file. Now I want to use this output from Hadoop and represent it graphically on R. The output file looks something like this.

```
1 overcast yes
1 rain 3 strong no
1 rain 3 weak yes
1 sunny 2 high no
1 sunny 2 normal yes
```

Is there a way that I can represent this graphically in R in something like,

http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~meeden/cs63/f05/figure3.1.jpg

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at package `'rpart'`.  It's a package for recursive partitioning and decision trees. The following is obtained directly from the example from the help file `?rpart`.  The function `expand.grid` may be of some use to you here as well.

```
> example(rpart)

fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)

fit2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
              parms = list(prior = c(.65,.35), split = "information"))

fit3 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
              control = rpart.control(cp = 0.05))

par(mfrow = c(1,2), xpd = NA) # otherwise on some devices the text is clipped

plot(fit)
text(fit, use.n = TRUE)
plot(fit2)
text(fit2, use.n = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried plotting this.. also went through the documentation of rpart. but it don't seem to find the solution to my problem.

Comment: You may want `dendrogram` then.  Try `example(dendrogram)`.  It has a large variety of plot examples.

Comment: What do the 1s represent in your data example?

Comment: 1 is the node number. In every row, a number represents the level. So 1 is the first level. after that if there is a number in the same row, it is set to next node level i.e 3 is on the second level. similary 2 is also on level 2.

Comment: (−1) this answer explains how to analyse a dataset in order to obtain a fitted decision tree. This is clearly not what is asked by apps92.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the text file into a data frame. This might be a good start: [Converting (web site) text file into data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302986/converting-web-site-text-file-into-data-frame-in-r)

Then you could use `'rpart'` to build a tree. In addition to '`rpart'` and it's `prp()`-function, you could also use the `'fancyRpartPlot'` in the ["rattle"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rattle/rattle.pdf)-package  to build fancier trees. [Here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/06/plotting-classification-and-regression-trees-with-plotrpart.html) is a good example.